# capture data of svn transaction in a text file

Tags: svn, batch-file, svn-hooks

How to capture data of svnlook changed command in a text file my pre commit hook is a bat file                                                             i tried the below command but i am not able to get data in txt file

```
svnlook changed -t %txn% %repos% >>logs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`svnlook changed` just gives the paths that were changed, you will have to loop over all the changed files and use `svnlook diff`